# Pandas : Why the order of merged keys are the way they are when we merge two DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to `pandas` and I am learning data manipulation. In the following example, while `merging` two `DataFrames` with some similar keys, why is the order of the keys in the merged DataFrame like below?

[image]

My question is, shouldn't the output be more like:

```
|0.  Z  1  3|

|1.  Y  2  2|

|2.  Z  3  3|
```

My logic is, first to go through each key in the first dataframe and check them in the 2nd one for each key because that's how it seems at first.

---

Note: This is my first time ever asking any question on this platform so please guide me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)- instead, paste your code as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting)

Comment: Seems to be a bug: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18776

Answer (score 1):

1. If you do not specify `on` keyword the intersection of the columns is used.

> on : label or list
>
> Column or index level names to join on. These must be found in both
> DataFrames. If `on` is None and not merging on indexes then this defaults
> to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames.

2. If you do not specify `sort` keyword, the output depends on the `how` parameter:

> sort : bool, default False
>
> Sort the join keys lexicographically in the result DataFrame. If False,
> the order of the join keys depends on the join type (how keyword).

3. If you do not specify `how` keyword, the default is to use inner join:

> how : {'left', 'right', 'outer', 'inner', 'cross'}, default 'inner'
>
> Type of merge to be performed.
>
> - inner: use intersection of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL inner
>   join; preserve the order of the left keys.

The order of the left keys is preserved (**not the index of left dataframe**) which is the case. All `Z` rows take the precedence over `Y` ones.

If you want your expected output, reset index on the left dataframe to preserve it when you merge and restore it after:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2).set_index('index').rename_axis(None).sort_index()
  key  data_set_1  data_set_2
1   Z           1           3
2   Y           2           2
3   Z           3           3
```